# Next JS. При названии страниц с большой буквы, в адрессной строке не работает обычный путь с маленькой буквы

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Делаю обычные странницы на next js, называю страницы типа Details.js и когда в адрессной строке есть путь localhost/details он выдает 404, это нормально? Делаю проект на npx create-next-app, вроде такое поведение не нормально?

Answer (score 0):

Если это первая страница (Входной файл) надо называть его index.js по дефолту
Пример: pages > news > index.js
И путь к странице будет localhost:3000/news
Судя по вашему примеру, Ваш путь должен быть таким localhost:3000/details/details
Возможно не так понял, но вроде это оно)

Comment: автор не продублировал вопрос, он в заголовке. имеется ввиду : [раз](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/139), [два](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/1211)

Comment: так что правильный ответ на этот вопрос будет - ссылка/цитата на спецификацию ?htttp протокола